# Options for building a "dynamic" OData Endpoint

Tags: .net, odata

What are my options if I want to build an OData service in .NET, without having a class for each record type in my entity models.
Basically, creating the $metadata on the fly based on, say, tables in a database.
Also, what gets exposed in that feed will vary according to authorization of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample addresses your requirement quite well:

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation/

Comment: Link is dead. Here are working ones:

https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiClassic/DynamicEdmModelCreation

https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/DynamicEdmModelCreation